# Forking shipping app has no effect in Django oscar

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-oscar

I had forked my shipping app into a folder called forked_apps using oscar_fork_app command and also added in settings.py get_core_apps(['forked_apps.shipping']), I just want to create two shipping methods mentioned, standard and express in the docs in this link:https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_configure_shipping.html.

In the **init**.py I have this code pre-existing:

```
default_app_config = 'forked_apps.shipping.config.ShippingConfig'
```

In repository.py I have written like this:

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import repository
from .methods import *


class Repository(repository.Repository):

    def get_available_shipping_methods(
            self, basket, user=None, shipping_addr=None,
            request=None, **kwargs):
        methods = (Standard())
        print("\n\nFetch availble shipping methods")
        if shipping_addr:
            # Express is only available in the UK
            methods = (Standard(), Express())

        return methods
```

And in the methods.py I had written:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
from oscar.apps.shipping import methods
from oscar.core import prices

class Standard(methods.FixedPrice):
    code = 'standard'
    name = 'Standard shipping'
    charge_excl_tax = D('5.00')

class Express(methods.FixedPrice):
    code = 'express'
    name = 'Express shipping'
    charge_excl_tax = D('10.00')
```

What should happen is, the shipping_methods.html page should show up, but instead, after entering the shipping address it goes to the payment details page directly; this would usually happen only if there are no shipping methods defined, but I have implemented two shipping methods, standard and Express in the above code.I can't figure out how to make this work, even the print statement isn't working.
Is there any other additional code that I must write?

Can someone provide a solution with some code, if you have implemented it?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted. Are you sure that the forked app is actually loading (does `__init__()` on your forked `Repository` class run?) and that the basket you are testing with requires shipping at all (this code would not run if no products in the basket have `requires_shipping` set to true on their product class)?

Comment: I think `methods = (Standard())` should be `methods = (Standard(),)`, else you are returning the wrong thing. In any case, the `print` statement should get executed, if it isn't, then there's some other issue as pointed out by solarissmoke. Is the `config.ShippingConfig` code intact?

Comment: Ok, so I did this in my shell >>> from forked_apps.shipping.repository import Repository
>>> r=Repository() , there's no errors after this.Is this the way to check if the init() is working?

Comment: No, that doesn't tell you whether your class is being loaded by Oscar. You need to load the class with `get_class()` and then check that what is returned is your class and not Oscar's default.

Comment: in settings.py you needed to replace 'oscar.apps.shipping.apps.ShippingConfig', with this 'apps.shipping.apps.ShippingConfig', after forking

Answer (score 1):

Remove oscar apps from settings.

For example:

```
#oscar.apps.checkout
#oscar.apps.shipping
```

etc.

Comment: Kindly suggest Django-Oscar beginner tutorials, except the documentation, where I can get step by step guide and explanation on using it and customising models and the already present Oscar apps and the templates?

Answer (score 1):

This section gives me error. I can't fix that.

```
get_available_shipping_methods(
    self, basket, user=None, shipping_addr=None,
    request=None, **kwargs):
...
```

> Django ver. > 2.1 | Oscar ver. > Latest

I using it like this;

```
mkdir customapp
touch customapp/__init__.py

python manage.py oscar_fork_app shipping customapp/
```

Edit settings.py

```
from oscar import get_core_apps
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps(
      ['customapp.shipping'])
```

In our customapp/shipping directory added new file, called (repository.py)

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import repository
from . import methods

class Repository(repository.Repository):

    methods = (methods.Standard(),)
```

Then add new file in same directory, customapp/shipping, called (methods.py)

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import methods
from oscar.core import prices
from decimal import Decimal as D

class Standard(methods.Base):
    code = 'standard'
    name = 'Shipping (Standard)'

    def calculate(self, basket):
        return prices.Price(
            currency=basket.currency,
            excl_tax=D('5.00'), incl_tax=D('5.00'))
```

You can add more methods.

Then run these commands;

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I figured it out a long time ago, thanks for your help:)